# How can you create a search that will search within a KML and display the results on a Google Map v3?

Tags: search, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I've created a Google map that loads a KML file as an overlay. It is a map of trailheads for say hiking. What I'm trying to figure out now is how to create a search that will allow visitors to search within the KML's data and show the relevant trailhead/s as results on the Google Map. Is this possible? I have a google search that will let them search for an address, but this does NOT search within the KML file's data for a trailhead.

Ideally the visitor could input an address, say 12345 Main st., Chicago, IL, or something and it would display results that are within a specified vicinity, say ten miles, of that address (ie latitude, longitude).

I'm a little lost as to even where to begin.

thanks for your help!

Davis

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how often your kml file updates, but i recommend storing all the kml data in a database as well to make this easier.  Maybe every once in a while re-download the kml file and update the database.

Then its as simple as using the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) and searching the database for nearby trails.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sounds like a good job for [Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/support/fusiontables/bin/answer.py?answer=184641&ft_source=tour_nav&__utma=1.1892795287.1297694907.1297694907.1297694907.1&__utmb=1.1.10.1297694907&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1297694907.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=%28organic%29|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=google%20maps%20fusion%20tables&__utmv=-&__utmk=79165716).  Fusion Tables give you a nice way to store and edit the data (even collaboratively).  In addition, there are geospatial columns/data fields you can add (aka, a "Location" column that can be address or lat/long coordinates).  Put all the trail heads in your fusion table and you can map them.  Let people enter an address or lat/long, and you can query the fusion table to show all trail heads within the user specified distance of that point.  See the tutorials to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can use KML search tool to do this.  It supports KML KMZ CSV and GPX.  You can find the tool [here](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Science-CAD/KML-Search-Tool.shtml)